# Transferir valor de um input para outro

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho um campo para pesquisa geral e outros campos de pesquisa segmentados (Pendentes, Vigentes, Encerrados), quero que tudo que for digitado no geral seja automaticamente passado para os segmentados.

Criei esta função que faz isso:

```
function myFunction() {
        $('#listaContratos').bootstrapTable('resetSearch', $('#myInput').val());
    }
```

Que é chamada quando é digitado algum valor na pesquisa geral:

```
<input class="form-control" id="myInput" onkeydown="myFunction()" type="text" placeholder="Pesquisar" />
```

Porém, na primeira vez que eu chamar a função, ainda não existe nada no "myInput", então sempre chega nas pesquisas segmentadas com um carácter a menos. Exemplo:
Enquanto no geral eu digitei 2353, no segmentado chega 235.

Como faço, pra quando a função ser chamada, também ser passado o valor que acabei de digitar?

Comment: Mude o evento onkeydown para onkeyup. Quando o evento onKeyDown é chamado, o carácter ainda não foi adicionado ao valor do input.

Comment: @DanielZazula isso mesmo, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Basta copiar o valor no evento On Key Up do Input de origem:

```js
function transferirValor() {
    jQuery('#inputDestino').val(jQuery('#inputOrigem').val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Origem: <input type="text" name="inputOrigem" id="inputOrigem" onkeyup="transferirValor()" />
Destino: <input type="text" name="inputDestino" id="inputDestino" />
```